# Cartesian product in pandas with uneven data

Tags: pandas, multi-index, cartesian-product

I've a input excel file as following:

[image]

And I need to make a cartesian product of this table as follows:

[image]

...

And so on until I get 3x4x2x3x4 = 288 rows.

How can I do this in `pandas`?

Comment: always helpful to share sample data in a reproducible form; you can do a ``df.to_dict('records')``, to share the data as a dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I've solved it using [pandas.MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
# Create sample data
data = 'A,B,C,D,E\nw2,a,xx,r1,50\nw4,b,mx,r2,51\nw8,c,,r5,52\n,d,,,53\n'
# Read sample for this we need to use read_csv with StrigIO as input
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
# Use MultiIndex 
# To get the expected result drop na values
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df[x].dropna().values for x in df.columns],names=df.columns)
# Create new dataframe using the multi-index
dfn = idx.to_frame(index=False)
print(dfn)
```

Comment: You can use `idx.to_frame(0)` instead of creating a new df and reset its index.